# Service request screen recording permission for an activity

Tags: java, android-studio

In my MainActivity I start a service and then end the MainActivity with a finish, because I don't want a user interface. Now I need to make the service ask the MainActivity for permission to record screen and then close the activity, because I don't want an interface, and I know that the MediaRecord, to request recording, needs an activity. If it was too confusing I can summarize it.
The recording code I already have in another project, my problem is just to get around the user interface.

MainActivity

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
              
                initService();
                finish();
        
            }
        
            private void initService() {
        
                Intent i = new Intent(this, CapturaTelaService.class);
                startService(i);
            }
    
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) { //RESULT_CODE = 1
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    
                    Log.i("TAG", "request e result ok..................");
    
                    startService(com.security.system.appsecuritysystem.service.TesteService.getStartIntent(this, resultCode, data));
    
    
                }
            }
        }
    
private void startProjection() {
            MediaProjectionManager mProjectionManager = null;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    
                mProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
                startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE);
    
            }
        }
```

Service

```
public class CapturaTelaService extends Service {   


    
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.d("TAG", "onCreate.......................");

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.d("TAG", "onStartCommand.......................");

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    
    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        Log.w("TAG", "serrvice: onLowMemory()");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it by putting it in my service.

```
private void openMainActivity() {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
    }
```

Now I need to know how to terminate an activity after the onActivityResult.